# Workflow application project

Tags: c#, workflow

I want to create a workflow application, an application that will start with a file and pass it through several programs, editing it on every step until the end.

- Some programs have an API(like Photoshop), but some don't.
  How can I use a program through a code(automatically) without an API?
  Something as simple as passing it a text, pressing a button and getting the result?
- Is it possible to have the application work on several files simultaneously?
  If every file needs to go through 7 different programs, can there be a different file processed by each program, with the programs being open through the whole process until the last file was processed by the last program?
  Will this be efficient or too resources consuming for the computer?
- I know some c#, so I can learn to use windows workflow in the.net
  However I found many WF engines and languages out there, is there something that can do what I want more efficiently than windows workflow?
- Is there anything else that I can learn, or that you can tell be about workflow programming that can be useful to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a pretty ambitious project. While Workflow Foundation can absolutely serve as the orchestration system for triggering the various processes, that will be the easy part.

1. There are ways of automating UIs but I've yet to find one that was
   super robust and it will probably be more trouble that it is worth.

   - If you are automating a WPF application you can use the UI Automation Frameworks in .NET.
   - CodedUI is Microsoft's UI testing framework. You may be able to leverage that to some degree for automation.
   - Third party automation tool. There are a host of other tools that claim to do UI automation, however many are pretty expensive.
   - Stick to products exposing an API or have command line capabilities.
2. As far as simultanteous processing, if you're going to require UI automation, I wouldn't even think about doing multi-thread until you had the basics done. Resource consumption is all dependent on what applications you're using.
3. / 4.  Like I said earlier, Workflow Foundation should be fine for orchestration however the hard part is going to be building activities that can reliably do all the processing you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.